# HtmlUnit won't change TextArea's text

Tags: java, htmlunit

I have written a code to connect to this webpage: compilerjava.net

1) I found the text-area field within that page which accepts the code to compile.

2) I have found the button that compiles the code.

3) I have found the text-area which returns the result of the code.

The issue is, when I call textarea.setText( "something"), it (I think) doesn't actually change the code in the webpage. So when I click on the compile button, it compiles the default code within that page and returns the output of that default code.

I have tried to set focus to textarea, you can see all of those down below.
I called;

1) textArea.focus();

2) textArea.click();

3) I tried using textArea.setAttribute( "name", "code");

I have searched the internet and found various stackoverflow questions close to this problem, neither of them solved my issue and it just seems to work for everyone when they say textArea.setText().

Another interesting fact I should share with you is,

If I call textArea.setText( "...") and then I say;

HtmlTextArea textArea1 = form.getTextAreaByName( "code");

If I call textArea1.getText(), the value of this text will be "...". This should imply that I have actually managed to change the value of the text-area, but when I compile, it compiles the default text in the text-area and not the text that I have set it to.

Any help with this?

P.S: The reason why I put the result of the compilation on a while loop is related to network connection issues. If you try to run this code it might not work on your first try. Also note that the run-time is around 15 seconds, because it gives thousands of warnings which I blocked to print to console.
P.S2: I also looked at this page and none of these worked;

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextArea

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Prevents the program to print thousands of warning codes.
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);

            // Initializes the web client and yet again stops some warning codes.
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient( BrowserVersion.CHROME);
            webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode( false);
            webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError( false);
            webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled( true);
            webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled( true);


            // Gets the html page, which is the online compiler I'm using.
            HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.compilejava.net/");


            // Succesfully finds the form which has the required buttons etc.
            List<HtmlForm> forms = page.getForms();
            HtmlForm form = forms.get( 0);


            // Finds the textarea which will hold the code.
            HtmlTextArea textArea = form.getTextAreaByName( "code");

            // Finds the textarea which will hold the result of the compilation.
            HtmlTextArea resultArea = page.getHtmlElementById( "execsout");

            // Finds the compile button.
            HtmlButtonInput button = form.getInputByName( "compile");

            textArea.click();
            textArea.focus();
            // Simple code to run.
            textArea.setDefaultValue( "public class HelloWorld\n" +
                    "{\n" +
                    "  // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor\n" +
                    "  public static void main(String[] args)\n" +
                    "  {\n" +
                    "    System.out.print( \"Hello\");\n" +
                    "  }\n" +
                    "}");

            System.out.println( textArea.getText());

            // Compiles.
            button.click();

            // Result of the compilation.
            String str = resultArea.getText();
            while ( resultArea.getText() == null || resultArea.getText().substring(0, 3).equals( "exe")) {
                System.out.print( resultArea.getText());
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println( resultArea.getText());

        } catch ( Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a little patience helps here

```
        // Result of the compilation.
        while (resultArea.getText() == null || resultArea.getText().startsWith("exe")) {
            System.out.println(resultArea.getText());
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(resultArea.getText());
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  As I said the problem lies with the fact that I can't change the text of the TextArea. That will print; "Why, Hello World! Isn't this something?" which is the default setting of the page. I'm trying to print out the result of my code, which I'm supposedly setting with textArea.setText() method.